# (Xcode) Command phasescriptexecution failed with a non-zero execution error (from EMPTY 2D iOS Unity Project)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, build

I've been working on this all day and I can't find a solution.

I'm using XCode 15 and iOS 17, and Unity Editor Version 2022.3.6f1.

After switching an EMPTY Unity Project to the iOS platform and then building it into a folder to run into XCode, XCode fails to build it, giving an error:
`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`
[image]

This is the full log:

```
Showing Recent Issues

Build target UnityFramework of project Unity-iPhone with configuration ReleaseForRunning
/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: warning: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported. (in target 'UnityFramework' from project 'Unity-iPhone')


/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported.


Build target Unity-iPhone of project Unity-iPhone with configuration ReleaseForRunning
/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: warning: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported. (in target 'Unity-iPhone' from project 'Unity-iPhone')


/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported.


Build target GameAssembly of project Unity-iPhone with configuration ReleaseForRunning
/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: warning: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported. (in target 'GameAssembly' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'GameAssembly' from project 'Unity-iPhone')


/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj: Ignoring ENABLE_BITCODE because building with bitcode is no longer supported.

Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.

PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GameAssembly.build/Script-C62A2A42F32E085EF849CF0B.sh (in target 'GameAssembly' from project 'Unity-iPhone')
    cd /Users/max/Desktop/flarpy\ borb\ xcode


[lots of exporting]


    /bin/sh -c /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GameAssembly.build/Script-C62A2A42F32E085EF849CF0B.sh

/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/il2cpp --compile-cpp --platform=iOS --baselib-directory=/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Libraries --additional-defines=IL2CPP_DEBUG=0 --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --dotnetprofile=unityaot-macos --profiler-report --print-command-line --external-lib-il2-cpp=/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Libraries/libil2cpp.a --generatedcppdir=Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --architecture=arm64 --outputpath=/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/libGameAssembly.a --cachedirectory=/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64 --configuration=Release
Starting: /Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/bee_backend/mac-arm64/bee_backend --profile="/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --beedriver-listener --dagfile="/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram
WorkingDir: /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate
ExitCode: 4 Duration: 0s153ms
ExitCode: 1 Duration: 0s2ms
Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones
Error: Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 1.
Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.ToolchainNotFoundException: IL2CPP C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Mac, you must have Xcode installed.
Building for Apple Silicon requires Xcode 9.4 and Mac 10.12 SDK.

Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.
It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.

More information and installation instructions can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.GetCompatibleXcodeInstallation(Architecture architecture, Version xcodeMinVersion, Version platformSdkMinVersion, Identifier platformSdkIdentifier, XcodePlatformSdk& compatiblePlatformSdk, XcodeInstallation& compatibleXcodeInstallation)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.UserAvailableToolchainFor(Architecture architecture, NPath toolChainPath, NPath sysRootPath)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.IL2CPPExeCompileCppBuildProgram.BuildProgram.Main(String[] args, String currentDirectory)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.InProcessBuildProgram.StartImpl(String workingDirectory, String[] arguments) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/InProcessBuildProgram.cs:line 51


Error: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones
Error: Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 1.
Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.ToolchainNotFoundException: IL2CPP C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Mac, you must have Xcode installed.
Building for Apple Silicon requires Xcode 9.4 and Mac 10.12 SDK.

Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.
It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.

More information and installation instructions can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here:
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.GetCompatibleXcodeInstallation(Architecture architecture, Version xcodeMinVersion, Version platformSdkMinVersion, Identifier platformSdkIdentifier, XcodePlatformSdk& compatiblePlatformSdk, XcodeInstallation& compatibleXcodeInstallation)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.UserAvailableToolchainFor(Architecture architecture, NPath toolChainPath, NPath sysRootPath)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.IL2CPPExeCompileCppBuildProgram.BuildProgram.Main(String[] args, String currentDirectory)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.InProcessBuildProgram.StartImpl(String workingDirectory, String[] arguments) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/InProcessBuildProgram.cs:line 51


   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/il2cpp/Program.cs:line 319
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/il2cpp --compile-cpp --platform=iOS --baselib-directory=/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Libraries --additional-defines=IL2CPP_DEBUG=0 --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --dotnetprofile=unityaot-macos --profiler-report --print-command-line --external-lib-il2-cpp=/Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Libraries/libil2cpp.a --generatedcppdir=Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --architecture=arm64 --outputpath=/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/libGameAssembly.a --cachedirectory=/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64 --configuration=Release

Starting: /Users/max/Desktop/flarpy borb xcode/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_arm64/bee_backend/mac-arm64/bee_backend --profile="/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --beedriver-listener --dagfile="/Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram

WorkingDir: /Users/max/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-efmjqelicbltevcfexdwscjgkreh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/artifacts/arm64/buildstate

ExitCode: 4 Duration: 0s153ms

ExitCode: 1 Duration: 0s2ms

Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones

Error: Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 1.

Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.ToolchainNotFoundException: IL2CPP C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Mac, you must have Xcode installed.

Building for Apple Silicon requires Xcode 9.4 and Mac 10.12 SDK.



Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.

It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.



More information and installation instructions can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/



Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/



Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!





   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.GetCompatibleXcodeInstallation(Architecture architecture, Version xcodeMinVersion, Version platformSdkMinVersion, Identifier platformSdkIdentifier, XcodePlatformSdk& compatiblePlatformSdk, XcodeInstallation& compatibleXcodeInstallation)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.UserAvailableToolchainFor(Architecture architecture, NPath toolChainPath, NPath sysRootPath)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.IL2CPPExeCompileCppBuildProgram.BuildProgram.Main(String[] args, String currentDirectory)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.InProcessBuildProgram.StartImpl(String workingDirectory, String[] arguments) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/InProcessBuildProgram.cs:line 51





Error: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: Build failed with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones

Error: Internal build system error. BuildProgram exited with code 1.

Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.ToolchainNotFoundException: IL2CPP C++ code builder is unable to build C++ code. In order to build C++ code for Mac, you must have Xcode installed.

Building for Apple Silicon requires Xcode 9.4 and Mac 10.12 SDK.



Xcode needs to be installed in the /Applications directory and have a name matching Xcode*.app. Or be selected using xcode-select.

It's also possible to use /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools if those match the listed requirements.



More information and installation instructions can be found here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/



Specific Xcode versions can be downloaded here:

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/



Unable to detect any compatible iPhoneOS SDK!





   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.GetCompatibleXcodeInstallation(Architecture architecture, Version xcodeMinVersion, Version platformSdkMinVersion, Identifier platformSdkIdentifier, XcodePlatformSdk& compatiblePlatformSdk, XcodeInstallation& compatibleXcodeInstallation)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.BuildLogic.iOS.iOSBuildLogic.UserAvailableToolchainFor(Architecture architecture, NPath toolChainPath, NPath sysRootPath)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Bee.IL2CPPExeCompileCppBuildProgram.BuildProgram.Main(String[] args, String currentDirectory)

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.InProcessBuildProgram.StartImpl(String workingDirectory, String[] arguments) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/Unity.IL2CPP.Building/InProcessBuildProgram.cs:line 51





   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(TinyProfiler2 tinyProfiler, String[] args, RuntimePlatform platform, Il2CppCommandLineArguments il2CppCommandLineArguments, BuildingOptions buildingOptions, Boolean throwExceptions) in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/il2cpp/il2cpp/Program.cs:line 319

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code



Build failed    8/11/23, 2:53 PM    6.2 seconds
```

I do have a phone connected running iOS 17:
[image]

And in the applications folder, I renamed "XCode-Beta" to just XCode"

Run Script:

```
HOST_ARCH=$(uname -m)
IL2CPP_DIR="$PROJECT_DIR/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy_$HOST_ARCH"
IL2CPP="$IL2CPP_DIR/il2cpp"
chmod +x "$IL2CPP"
if [ "$HOST_ARCH" = "arm64" ];
then
    HOST_ARCH_BEE="arm64"
else
    HOST_ARCH_BEE="x64"
fi
chmod +x "$IL2CPP_DIR/bee_backend/mac-$HOST_ARCH_BEE/bee_backend"
if [ "$CONFIGURATION" = "Debug" ];
then
    IL2CPP_CONFIG="Debug"
else
    IL2CPP_CONFIG="Release"
fi
"$IL2CPP" --compile-cpp --platform=iOS --baselib-directory="$PROJECT_DIR/Libraries" --additional-defines=IL2CPP_DEBUG=0 --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --dotnetprofile=unityaot-macos --profiler-report --print-command-line --external-lib-il2-cpp="$PROJECT_DIR/Libraries/libil2cpp.a" --generatedcppdir="Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput" --architecture=arm64 --outputpath="$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/libGameAssembly.a" --cachedirectory="$CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR/artifacts/arm64" --configuration="$IL2CPP_CONFIG"
```

Changing 'for install builds only' only gives more errors.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Identical issue in all aspects.

Fixed by updating the Unity Editor to 2022.3.10.f1

Comment: Same! I was using 2022.2.05f1 & shifted to 2022.3.15f1 and it worked smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

Rolling back to Xcode 15 Beta 5 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

update: Just install Xcode 15.0 and Xcode 15.0 beta5 in Applications.

I also saw someone giving feedback on similar issues on the official Unity forum. It seems that we can only wait for Unity officials to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using Unity Editor (intel) version on M1 silicon processor. You may try to install silicon version of Unity Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Using Unity Silicon Versions if you have an M1 processor, do a clean build from the MAC, and also add the -ld64 in Other Linker flags, like in the following link : https://forum.unity.com/threads/project-wont-build-using-xode15-release-candidate.1491761/page-2. I was using Unity 2022.3.14f1 with Xcode 15.01. Hope it helps.

Be mindful please, it is -LD64 (all lowercase) and NOT -ID64